# Estimating the region of attraction of a non-linear system with a Lyapunov Function

Tags: nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I'm trying to estimate the region of attraction of the following system:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\dot{x}_1 = \sin(x_2) \\
\dot{x}_2 = -x_1 - \sin(x_2). 
\end{gathered}
$$

From Khalil, I know that if I define V as follows:
$$
V(x) = x^TPx,
$$
where $P$ is the solution of
$$
PA+A^TP=-I,
$$
will yield the best results for an estimate.
The unique equilibrium point of the system is in the origin, and it is asymptotically stable. Linearizing around the origin, I obtain the following:
$$A =
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1\\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
\text{ and }
P = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
3/2 & 1/2 \\
 1/2 & 1\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
.$$From which
$$
V(x) = (3x_1^2)/2 + (x_1x_2) + x_2^2
$$
taking its derivative and substituting the initial system:
$$
\dot{V}(x) = -sin(x_2)(x_2-2x_1) - x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 
$$
Introducing the following relations:
$$
|x_1|\leq\|x\|, \quad |x_1x_2|\leq\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2, \quad |x_2 - 2x_1|\leq\sqrt5\|x\|, \quad |sinx|\leq1
$$
It is possible to write:
$$
\dot{V}(x) \leq-\sqrt5\|x\| - 2\|x\|^2
$$
This expression is less than $0$ only for:
$$
\|x\|\leq-\sqrt5/2 \
\text{ and } \
\|x\|\geq0
$$
The first one is clearly impossible because the $\|x\|$ is always positive. If I choose the second one, I should select $r = 0$, and so the region of attraction should be null too because from Khalil:
$$
V(x) < c = \lambda_{min}(P)*r^2
$$
This sound quite strange to me because the origin is asymptotically stable, so the region of attraction should be not null. Any help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the derivative of $V$ is correct?

Comment: I think when you compute $\dot{V}$, you need to plug in the linearized equations, not the fully nonlinear ones.

Comment: @KBS I substituted the initial system in the time derivative, I have just checked again and it is correct.

Comment: The error is that $V(x)=x^TPx=3x_1^2/2+x_1x_2+x_2^2$.

Comment: This $1/2$ is pretty useless and it is better to skip it here because it leads to simpler expressions.

Comment: @KBS Without the $1/2$ I obtained $\dot{V}(x) = 2x_1\sin(x_2) - x_2\sin(x_2) - x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2$ that is almost equal to that I found before. The problem is again in finding a relation between $||x||$ and the $sin(x)$

Comment: Where is that problem coming from?

Comment: @KBS I think I solved it. It should be enough to collect $sin(x_2)$, and consider its absolute value always less than 1. The others terms are easily manageable. What do you think?

Comment: I cannot evaluate your solution solely based on this comment. Please, update your post with your calculations. But you have not replied to my previous question. Where is this problem coming from?

Comment: @KBS Done! Let me know.

Comment: Where is the term $-2||x||^2$ coming from? That does not seem to be correct since we do not have $-x_1^2-2x_1x_2\le -2||x||^2$. Also, we do not have that $-|x_1x_2|\leq-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$ but $-|x_1x_2|\geq-\frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @KBS ok, and what about the inequality? what do you compute?

Comment: I am just saying that you are using the inequalities in the wrong way, which results in incorrect results.

Comment: @ColeG97 No, using the linearized equations would not make sense since the task is to estimate the region of attraction of the nonlinear system. A stable linear system is always globally stable, so asking for its region of attraction would be redundant.

Comment: @SampleTime true. I checked again my resolution and it is wrong because it is impossible to obtain the $||x||$ less than a negative number. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the system

$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1&=\sin(x_2)\\
\dot{x}_2&=-x_1-\sin(x_2)
\end{align}
$$

which has the linearization matrix

$$
A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0&\cos{x_2}\\-1&-\cos{x_2}\end{pmatrix}
$$

which at the origin is

$$
A=A(0)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now taking $Q=I$ you can solve

$$
PA+A^TP=-Q
$$

for $P>0$ and get $P=\begin{pmatrix}3/2&1/2\\1/2&1\end{pmatrix}$ so that

$$
V(x)=x^TPx=3 x_1^2/2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^2
$$

Now finding a region of attraction can be done by solving

$$
k=\min_x V(x) \text{ s.t. } \dot{V}(x)=0, x\neq0
$$

This is a constrained minimization problem:

$$
\begin{align}
k=&\min_x\quad 3 x_1^2/2 + x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 \\
&\text{ s.t. } \quad 2 x_1\sin(x_2) - 2 x_1 x_2 - x_2 \sin(x_2) - x_1^2=0\\
&\phantom{\text{ s.t. }}\quad x\neq0
\end{align}
$$

This is not easy to solve analytically but we can solve it numerically. We can solve $\dot{V}(x)=0$ for $x_2$ and get two different solutions which we can substitute in $V(x)$ to get:

$$
V_1(x_2)=\frac{\left(2\,x_{2}-3\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)\right)\,\left(3\,x_{2}-2\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)+2\,\sqrt{{x_{2}}^2-3\,x_{2}\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)+{\sin\left(x_{2}\right)}^2}\right)}{2}
$$

and

$$
V_2(x_2)=-\frac{\left(2\,x_{2}-3\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)\right)\,\left(2\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)-3\,x_{2}+2\,\sqrt{{x_{2}}^2-3\,x_{2}\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)+{\sin\left(x_{2}\right)}^2}\right)}{2}
$$

both assuming ${x_{2}}^2-3\,x_{2}\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)+{\sin\left(x_{2}\right)}^2\geq 0.$ Now we can plot both functions:

[image]

In this image, only the parts of $V_1$ and $V_2$ are plotted where ${x_{2}}^2-3\,x_{2}\,\sin\left(x_{2}\right)+{\sin\left(x_{2}\right)}^2\geq 0.$ We can now see that we have two minima, which we can use to compute $x_1$. We end up with two solutions:

$$
\begin{align}
(x_1,x_2)&=(0.9885, -2.2013)\\
(x_1,x_2)&=(-0.9885, 2.2013)
\end{align}
$$

The first corresponds to the minimum of the blue graph, the second to the minimum of the red graph. In both cases we have

$$
k=V(0.9885,-2.2013)=V(-0.9885,2.2013)=4.1355
$$

which is the level you are looking for. We can confirm this by checking another plot:

[image]

- Teal: $\dot{V}(x)\leq 0$
- Dark blue: $\dot{V}(x)> 0$
- Yellow: $\dot{V}(x)\leq 0$ and $V(x)\leq k$
- Black cross: origin
- Blue dot: first solution $(x_1,x_2)=(0.9885, -2.2013)$
- Red dot: second solution $(x_1,x_2)=(-0.9885, 2.2013)$

Note however that the yellow area in general is only a subset of the region of attraction.

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant solution. I'm wondering if the same solution could be reached even with my procedure, so utilizing the formula I found on Khalil ($c = \lambda_{min}(P)*r^2$) and exploiting relations with the $||x||$.